# How to make triangle tightly (no space) enclose other triangles using "fit"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit, tikz-shape

I am trying, so far with negative result, to enclose a couple of triangles in a bigger triangle without leaving any space between them.

Output (dashed green line I drew by hand; this is where I need the enclosing triangle to be positioned at):

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary
{%
    fit,
    positioning,
    shapes.geometric
}

\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=1pt}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [%
            every isosceles triangle node/.style=
            {%
                inner sep=0mm,
                outer sep=0mm,
                isosceles triangle apex angle=60
            }
        ]%

        % TOP TRIANGLE
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                draw=red,fill=red!20,
                minimum size=20mm
            ]   (T1){};

        % BOTTOM TRIANGLE
        %  (ALIGNED TO TOP TRIANGLE'S LEFT CORNER)
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                below=0mm of T1.left corner,
                anchor=apex,
                draw=red,fill=red!20,
                minimum size=20mm
            ]   (T2){};

        % ENCLOSING TRIANGLE
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                line width=0pt,
                draw,
                fit=(T1)(T2)
            ]   (ENCLOSURE){};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try `fit=(T1.north east)(T2.south east)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small Changes:

- use `fit=(T1.north east)(T2.south east)` instead of `fit=(T1)(T2)`
- option: `dashed,thick,green,` -> green and dotted line

Or with some space:

- `\usepackage{calc}` -> for relative coordinates
- for example (border = `0.05`): change `fit` to `fit={($(T1.north east)+(0.05,0)$)($(T2.south east)+(-0.05,-0.05)$)}`

Result:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
{%
    fit,
    positioning,
    shapes.geometric,
    calc
}
%\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=1pt}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [%
            every isosceles triangle node/.style=
            {%
                inner sep=0mm,
                outer sep=0mm,
                isosceles triangle apex angle=60
            }
        ]%

        % TOP TRIANGLE
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                draw=red,fill=red!20,
                minimum size=20mm
            ]   (T1){};
        % BOTTOM TRIANGLE
        %  (ALIGNED TO TOP TRIANGLE'S LEFT CORNER)
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                below=0mm of T1.left corner,
                anchor=apex,
                draw=red,fill=red!20,
                minimum size=20mm
            ]   (T2){};
        % ENCLOSING TRIANGLE
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                shape border rotate=90,
                line width=0pt,
                draw,
                dashed,thick,green,
                %fit=(T1.north east)(T2.south east)
                fit={($(T1.north east)+(0.05,0)$)($(T2.south east)+(-0.05,-0.05)$)}
            ]   (ENCLOSURE){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```